# Undeclared identifier in c++

Tags: c++

I want to print three number from maximum to minimum for 3 numbers, when I try to compile this code it shows me this error  `C2065 "function parameter :Undeclared identifier function parameter"`for every function arguments . other error is `C 2062 type "int" unexpected`.
Here is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int max, min;//making global variable  of max and min 

void numMax(int x, int y, int z);//finding maximum number
void numMin(int x, int y, int z);/finding minimum number

int main()
{
    int x, int y, int z;
    int middle = 0;

    cout << "This program will take 3 number and print them from minimum to maximum" << endl;
    cout << "_________________" << endl;
    cout << "Pleas enter three number" << endl;
    cout << "num1 =";cin >> x;cout << endl << "\n";
    cout << "num2 =";cin >> y;cout << endl << "\n";
    cout << "num3 =";cin >> z;cout << endl << "\n";

    numMax(x, y, z);
    numMin(x, y, z);


    if (x<max & x>min) 
    {
        middle = x;
    }
    if (y<max & y>min) 
    {
        middle = y;
    }
    if (z<max & z>min) 
    {
        middle = z;
    }

    cout <<"ordered numbers are : "<< min << "\t"<< middle << "\t" <<max ;

    return 0;
}



void numMAx(int x, int y, int z)
{
    int max;

    max = x > y ? x : y;
    max = z > max ? z : max;
    cout << max;
}

void numMin(int x, int y, int z)
{
    int min;

    min = x < y ? x : y;
    min = min<z ? min : z;
    cout << min;
}
```

first I have defined my functions, then in main function I have passed parameter to function argument then I have mentioned my numMax and numMin fuctions to excute their task. finally I have used `if` statement for determining middle number. What should I do ?

Comment: int x, int y, int z; => int x, y, z;

Comment: If you check your post on SO, you'll see that your comment contains a single forward slash '/' instead of double slash '//'.

Comment: did you notice that you declared void numMax(int x, int y, int z); but implemented void numMAx(int x, int y, int z);
Note the capital A in the function name in implementation, while in declaration it is numMax;

Comment: Also note that your global variables are useless, since in functions you have local variables with same name, so global variables will not be updated

Comment: And change int x, int y, int z; -----> int x,y,z;

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int     numMax    (int x,int y ,int z)
{
 if(x>y && x>z)    
    return x;    
else if (y>x && y>z)    
    return y;    
else    
    return z;    
}    


int numMin(int x,int y ,int z)
{

if(x<y && x<z)
    return x;
else if (y<x && y<z)
    return y;
else
    return z;
}

void main()
{
int x,y,z;
int max,min;
clrscr();

cout<<"\n Enter 3 Number: \n";

cout<<"1st Num: ";cin>>x;
cout<<"2nd Num: ";cin>>y;
cout<<"3rd Num: ";cin>>z;
max = numMax(x,y,z);
min = numMin(x,y,z);
if(x<max && x>min)
{
    middle=x;
}
else if(y<max && y>min)
{
    middle=y;
}
else
    middle=z;

cout<<"Number from max to min are: \n "<<numMax(x,y,z)<<" "<<numMin(x,y,z)<<" "<<middle;
}
```

try this